# Modulo of factorial

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

How do I solve for M modulo 2021 where M is the product of all numbers relatively prime to 2021 that are less than 2021.
I know Wilson's Theorem but that's applicable for modulo p where p is prime. Should I use CRT by breaking 2021 into 43 and 47 but even that seems intractable to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $2020!$ has several factors of $43$ and $47$

Comment: Of course the remainder is $0$.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Yes it is the case why do you think it isnt?

Comment: I have edited the problem as I spotted a mistake in definition of M

Answer (score 1):

All of these numbers will have multiplicative inverses (mod 2021), so they all cancel, with the exception of those numbers which are their own inverses. So $M$ is the product of the residues whose square is $1$.

We can find all such $x$ using the CRT to be $1, 988, 1033, 2020$. So their product $M = 1$.